# Imagemagick convert PDF => PDF multipage

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I've various PDF files from differents origins.. charged from users in a website..

I want reduce size of those more than 700Ko
So, I've make a script for select all files bigger than 700Ko;

For each PDF ( because there's images too ) I make :

```
exec('convert -density 300 -trim "'.$file.'" -resize 1000 -quality 85 -colorspace RGB -background white  "'.$destination.$rand.$save_to.'" &', $output, $return_var);
```

The & at the end is for make : page-1.png, page-2.png ...

All is OK at this nivel ( I use .png because with .jpg I've some black background.. :( )

After, I try to make a new PDF with this:

```
exec('convert '.$img.' +page -quality 100 -gravity center '.$dirname.'/page1.pdf');
```

where $img is a list of image .png 
Here, I've a problem .. most of image are not centered in the page..

How to make each page with a 100% size with the image, without border??

Answer (score 0):

So, I've find a solution for my problem ..

I use Ghostscript .. better, faster and without problem.;
my code:

```
exec('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook  -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile='.$rand.' '.$file.' ',$output, $return_var);
```

All PDF are smaller and don't lose quality !

More informations : http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/